# I want to show/hide 'p' when the heading of that paragraph clicked using jQuery but as of now I am just trying to show 'p'

Tags: jquery

This is my jQuery. Here I am trying .next()

```
    var trigger =  $('alpha')
    $('h2').click(function(){    
       click = click.next('p');
       $('p').css('display', 'block');
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` does not refer to anything. You want to use `$(this)` to access to the clicked element.

Also, you can use `.toggle()` to easily show/hide elements:

```js
$('h2').click(function() {
  $(this).next('p').toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Title 1</h2>
<p>Text 1</p>

<h2>Title 2</h2>
<p>Text 2</p>

<h2>Title 3</h2>
<p>Text 3</p>
```